# Difficullty debugging Grails & Tomcat8 error

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, tomcat8

Trying to deploy my Grails application(ver. 1.3.9) the only location where I found a logged issue is the `localhost.log` located in the `/var/log/tomcat8` folder.

The stacktrace is only a few lines long leaving me to wonder how to fix the error. Any ideas?

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
        ... 3 more
```

The strange this is also that the application works fine on localhost and only has problem deploying on a server machine

**EDIT:**

**var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/app/WEB_INF/applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

        <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
                <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
                <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
        </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean">
        <property name="grailsResourceHolder" ref="grailsResourceHolder" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceHolder" scope="prototype" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsResourceHolder">
        <property name="resources">
              <value>**/grails-app/**/*.groovy</value>
        </property>
    </bean>    

   <bean id="characterEncodingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
          <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
   </bean>      
</beans>
(END)
```

Comment: Post bean definition for pluginManager.

Comment: Could you provide more details...

Comment: Post your applicationContext.xml